# Backbone fetch not fetching correctly

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I seem to be fetching correctly from the server using backbone. A GET request is made to a MongDB collection, via the Node.js server code here:

```
exports.getTeams = function(req,res,next){

    var system_db = req.system_db;
    var user_id = req.mainUser._id;

    var teams = teamModel.getNewTeam(system_db,user_id);

    teams.find({}, function (err, items) {
        res.json(items);
    });
};
```

I am fetching from Backbone like so:

```
var teamCollection = new TeamCollection([]);
teamCollection.url = '/api/teams';
teamCollection.fetch(
    {success:function(){
        console.log('teamCollection length:',teamCollection.length);
        console.log('teamCollection[0]:',teamCollection[0]);
    }}
);
```

using this model and collection:

```
var Team = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: "_id",
    urlRoot: 'http://localhost:3000/api/teams'
});

var TeamCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Team,
    initialize: function() {
        this.bind('add', this.onModelAdded, this);
        this.bind('remove', this.onModelRemoved, this);
        this.bind("change", this.onModelChanged, this);
    },
   /* parse: function(data) {
        //return JSON.stringify(data).objects;
        //return JSON.parse(data).objects;
        return data.objects;
    },*/
    onModelAdded: function(model, collection, options) {
        console.log("added, options:", options);
    },
    onModelRemoved: function (model, collection, options) {
        console.log("removed, options:", options);
    },
    onModelChanged: function (model, collection, options) {
        console.log('Collection has changed.');
    },
    comparator: function (model) {
        return model.get("_id");
    }
});
```

the problem is that the logging statements above log the following in the browser console:

[image]

It says I am sending 4 items from the server to the Backbone client, but the first one is undefined. How could this be?

Answer (score 1):

A `Backbone.Collection` is not an array-like object : it has a `length` attribute representing the number of models but you can't access individual models via indexes, hence

```
console.log(teamCollection[0]); //undefined
```

To get a model at a given position, use [`collection.at`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-at) .Try

```
console.log(teamCollection.at(0));
```

And a demo of those behaviors http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/013gjpny/